# How do I bind an NSArrayController to a property on the App's delegate in a Storyboard in Xcode 10 (macOS)?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode10, macos-mojave

With Nib/Xib files, there's an Application object in each .xib. But with Storyboards, I don't see any way to bind objects across scenes. I need an App or AppDelegate proxy object in my scene, but it's not clear how to get that and ensure it points to the singleton AppDelegate object in my code.

Comment: See [What is the new way of binding an NSArrayController to the managed object context of a Core Data document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184218/what-is-the-new-way-of-binding-an-nsarraycontroller-to-the-managed-object-contex/28185403#28185403)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this because it adds a lot of cross-dependency (I have to write code that’s intimately familiar with the view hierarchy in order to set a property down in an embedded view controller). This app is not document-based and doesn’t use Core Data, but it does benefit from a singleton data store.

Comment: See [Technical Q&A QA1871 Cocoa Bindings in OS X Storyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1871/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016747).